# Calculating previous last purchase price if value is less than 10 SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following subquery within my select query that gets the last purchase date of a product, purchase date, order number and vendor based on the last purchase date. However, I need to modify it so that if the last purchase is less than $10 it will go the next last purchase date and so forth and populate the purchase date, order number and vendor accordingly.

Any suggestions how I would do that??

Comment: you should put more effort into formatting your code next time..

Comment: I seen no code in the question, looks like edit 3 removed it all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `purchamt >= 10` condition should help

```
,LastPurchase=(SELECT TOP (1) purchamt AS LastPurchase 
FROM purchase AS p 
WHERE (masterid = m.masterid) 
    AND (purchvendorid <> '')
    AND purchamt >= 10
ORDER BY purchasedate DESC)

,PurchaseDate=(SELECT TOP (1) purchasedate 
FROM purchase AS p 
WHERE (masterid = m.masterid) 
    AND (purchvendorid <> '')
    AND purchamt >= 10
ORDER BY purchasedate DESC)

,PONo=(SELECT TOP 1 do.orderno 
FROM [purchase] p INNER JOIN dealorder do on do.orderid = p.purchasepoid 
WHERE (masterid = m.masterid) 
    AND (purchvendorid <> '')
    AND purchamt >= 10
ORDER BY purchasedate DESC)

,vendor=(SELECT TOP 1 v.vendor 
FROM [purchase] p INNER JOIN vendor v on v.vendorid = p.purchvendorid 
WHERE (masterid = m.masterid) 
    AND (purchvendorid <> '')
    AND purchamt >= 10
ORDER BY purchasedate DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i have understood your question correctly or not but all you want is the purchase amount should be > 10  just add that in your subquery. It will ignore all the purchase dates where amount < 10.

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT TOP (1) purchamt AS LastPurchase 
FROM purchase AS p 

WHERE (masterid = m.masterid) 
    AND (purchvendorid <> '')
    and purchamt  > 10
ORDER BY purchasedate DESC
```